# Is there any difference between these multi-line comments in Java?

Tags: java, comments

I just wanted to know if there are any differences between these types of comments.

```
/* 
...    
Content of the comment
...    
*/
```

and

```
/* 
* ...    
* Content of the comment
* ...    
*/
```

Comment: besides the number of asterixes used, no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no difference. It's purely a style decision.

Answer (score 3):

No difference, but this syntax

```
/* 
* ...    
* Content of the comment
* ...    
*/
```

is more appropriate for generating JavaDoc

From http://javadude.com/articles/comments.html

> Documentation comments should (at very least) be used in front of
>   every public class, interface, method and class/instance variable in
>   your source code. This allows someone to run javadoc against the code
>   and generate a simple document that lists the public entities and a
>   brief description of each. You may also use documentation comments in
>   front on non-public methods, and use a javadoc option to generate
>   documentation for them. Using documentation comments on non-public
>   entities is not as important as publics (the interface isn't
>   exposed...) but if you're commenting the code anyway you might as well
>   write those comments as documentation comments.

Answer (score 3):

No it makes no difference.

**Side Note** (for the sake of completeness)
There is a difference between the following to examples.

```
/* 
* ...    
* Content of the comment
* ...    
*/
```

and

```
/**
* ...    
* Content of the comment
* ...    
*/
```

the second one indicates a javadoc comment (the ** at the first line of the comment). There you can use different tags to enhance your javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any difference. Just a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer the first form:

```
/*

something

*/
```

Specially if the commented out part is code and if I am trying something out. For obvious reasons, extra asterixes at the beginning of each line causes head aches for this case.

Modern IDE's also support short-cuts for commenting multiple lines at the same time. For example in Eclipse, you can select a few lines and press CTRL + / to comment them out. The form of comments is though would be as follows:

```
// line1
// line2
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference

As a developer What ever the code we are writing we need to make a small document on top of that particular code.for documenting purpose we will use these comments based on our choice we can use what ever we want.